# SoundCloud API: Ordering by hotness with the "created_at" filter doesn't work

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to determine the hottest tracks in the range of May 1 2012 to May 10 2012.

Unfortunately, the following query returns an empty set of tracks:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?limit=20&order=hotness&created_at[from]=2012-05-01&created_at[to]=2012-05-10&consumer_key=
```

It is however clear that there exist tracks created in that range of time because the same query works when the order parameter is omitted:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?limit=20&created_at[from]=2012-05-01&created_at[to]=2012-05-10&consumer_key=
```

I was hoping for the hotness algorithm to work across any range of time.

The other strange thing I found is that when a query parameter is specified along side the hotness and created_at parameters, results are returned:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?limit=20&order=hotness&created_at[from]=2012-05-01&created_at[to]=2012-05-10&q=a&consumer_key=
```

Unfortunately it looks like the results are not sorted by hotness (though I think they may have been at some point in the past).

Any tips on how to get a list of tracks sorted by hotness within a specific time range?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It looks like you have the date format incorrect according to https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks It is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: also I think hotness is now deprecated; src: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param

Answer (score 0):

The hotness parameter has been [deprecated](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param) as of April 16th, 2013.  As an alternative, you can rank tracks based on the number of plays (`playback_count`), downloads (`download_count`), favorites (`favoritings_count`), comments (`comment_count`), likes (`likes_count`), or reposts (`reposts_count`) on a `track` object.